# Prove that $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of the group $(G, \circ)$

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

**Question:** Let $(G, \circ)$ be a group and $H$ be a non-empty subset of $G$. A relation $\rho$ defined on $G$ by $$a\,\rho\ b\quad \text{if and only if}\quad a\circ b^{-1}\in H$$ for $a,b\in G$, is an equivalence relation on $G$. Prove that $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$.

*Progress:*  To show $(H, \circ)$ is a sub-group it is enough to show  $a,b\in H\implies a\circ b^{-1}\in H$. How can I show this?

Comment: First, use reflexivity to show that the identity element is in $H$. Then use symmetry to show that inverses of elements in $H$ are in $H$. Finally, use transitivity to show that products are in $H$.

Comment: @TK, Thanks for your hints., I have little doubt. If $a\in H$ then how can I sure $a\rho a$ holds. Please explain.

Comment: Use that the relation is reflexive, so $a\rho a$ holds for all $a\in G$ (not just those in $H$).

Comment: @TK, can you explain with detailed answer. Thanks

Comment: No, I prefer to leave the solving to you now that I have given an outline.

Comment: Actually, the condition that $H$ is nonempty is redundant in the problem statement. The three defining properties of "equivalence relation" are in a pretty one-to-one-correspondence with required properties of a subgroup ...

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am not sure if the tag for congruence relations is really suitable here, as this relation is such precisely when the subgroup is normal, but that part is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You're probably right. I have [removed the tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1772322/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

We first show that $e\in H$. By the reflexivity of $\rho$, $e\rho e$, and hence, $e=e\circ e^{-1}\in H$.

Next, we show that $a,b\in H\implies a\circ b^{-1}\in H$. Assume $a, b\in H$. Then, $a\circ e^{-1}= a\in H$ and $b\circ e^{-1}=b\in H$. By assumption, it follows that $a\rho e$ and $b\rho e$. Since $\rho$ is symmetric, we have $e\rho b$, and hence, by transitivity, $a\rho b$, as well. Therefore, $a\circ b^{-1}\in H$. This is what is required to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already seen that *if* $H$ is a subgroup, then $\rho$ is an equivalence relation. The proof uses the properties of subgroups:

1. $e\in H$
2. if $a\in H$, then $a^{-1}\in H$
3. if $a,b\in H$, then $ab\in H$

The relation $\rho$ is reflexive: indeed, if $a\in G$, then $aa^{-1}=e\in H$ by 1, so $a\mathrel{\rho}a$

The relation $\rho$ is symmetric: indeed, if $a\mathrel{\rho}b$, we have $ab^{-1}\in H$, so $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=ba^{-1}\in H$, for 2; therefore $b\mathrel{\rho}a$.

The relation $\rho$ is transitive: indeed, if $a\mathrel{\rho}b$ and $b\mathrel{\rho}c$, then $ab^{-1}\in H$ and $bc^{-1}\in H$, so $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})=ac^{-1}\in H$ by 3; therefore $a\mathrel{\rho}c$.

---

The converse proof follows a very similar pattern.

Since $\rho$ is reflexive, we have $e\mathrel{\rho}e$, that is, $ee^{-1}=e\in H$.

If $a\in H$, then $ae^{-1}=a\in H$; therefore $a\mathrel{\rho}e$ and, since the relation is symmetric, also $e\mathrel{\rho}a$, which means $ea^{-1}=a^{-1}\in H$.

If $a,b\in H$, we have $a=(ab)b^{-1}\in H$ and therefore $ab\mathrel{\rho}b$; moreover $b\mathrel{\rho}e$, so $ab\mathrel{\rho}e$ by transitivity; hence $ab=abe^{-1}\in H$.